# Movie about a couple moving into a neighborhood and are acually salespeople?

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

What's that movie about a couple moving into a neighborhood, having a "perfect" life and they are trying to impress and influence the neighbors to buy things. They are acually employed salepeople.

Comment: Do you have any more details for us to go off of?  Year, when you viewed it, animated or not, general tone of the film, plot, ending, anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be this one: [The Joneses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Joneses). From the plot summary:

> Kate, Steve, Mick, and Jenn Jones move into a high income suburb under the pretense of being a typical family relocating due to the changing nature of Kate and Steve's careers. In reality, Kate is the leader of a team of stealth marketers, professional salespeople who disguise product placement as a daily routine.

Answer (score 6):

The movie is [The Joneses](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1285309/), released in 2009 starring David Duchovny and Demi Moore.

Comment: If you could add a reason why you think this is the movie, or provide some reference to your assumption, this answer would gather a lot more votes :)

Comment: Sorry @M.A I was writing my answer while yours was posted: you got there first.

Comment: @TylerShads: noted and thanks. I see that matt has already added a plot summary, so that should do it.

Comment: @matt_black: no worries.